# Python Flask. Переход между страницами с использованием декоратора и wtf form

Tags: python, flask, декоратор

Пытаюсь разбираться с Flask.
Хочу чтоб различные пользователи могли после авторизации заполнять некие формы, данные из которых (пока) просто сохраняю в текстовом файлы.
Пишу декоратор вида :

```
@app.route('/fill', methods=['GET', 'POST'])                       #процедура заполнение формы
def fill():
    form = FillF()
...


@app.route('/log', methods=['GET', 'POST'])                         #процедура логин
def log():
    form = AuthF()
...
```

После проверки регистрационных данных нужно выполнить вызов процедуры заполнения формы с передачей  неких данных, например имени пользователя. Но тут возникают проблемы.

Вызов в виде функции не работает

```
def fill(*args)
```

Вызов страницы через шаблонизатор вот такого вида

```
return render_template('fill.html', form=FillF(), filename = filename, username = username, round_num = round_num)
```

загружает нужную форму, но не переходит в соответствующую функцию fill. Форма заполняется, но не происходит запись в файл.

Получается перейти только через `return (redirect(url_for('fill')))`
Но эта функция не подразумевает передачи аргументов, например имя пользователя

**Вопрос, как правильно это сделать?**
если нужно, более полный код на гитхаб https://github.com/VladimirPyat/Flask_test